# Get data from Cache (Web API)

Tags: jquery, caching, get

Models CPacket:

```
namespace QuoteAPI.Models
{
    public class CPacket
    {
        public string key { get; set; }
        public Value value { get; set; }
        public int duration { get; set; }
    }
    public class Value
    {
        public string code { get; set; }
        public List<List<double>> data { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I want to get data from Cache.
Data:

```
[
  {
    "key": "key1",
    "value": {
      "code": "CTG",
      "data": [
        [
          1,
          12.7
        ],
        [
          2,
          3.12
        ]
      ]
    },
    "duration": 5
  },
  {
    "key": "key1",
    "value": {
      "code": "CTE",
      "data": [
        [
          1,
          12.8
        ],
        [
          2,
          5.12
        ]
      ]
    },
    "duration": 8
  }
]
```

I have funtion save cache:

```
[HttpPost]
        public string Post([FromBody] string strPostData)
        {
            var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CPacket>>(strPostData);
            foreach (var item in model)
            {
                MemoryCache.Default.Add(item.key, item.value, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(item.duration));
            } 
            return "OK";
        }
```

I want use Jquery to call data from Cache. Now I use Array Key (I knew), and send key from controller QuoteControllers. I think it have a error when return (null)

```
[HttpPost]
        public string Post(string id)

        {
            return MemoryCache.Default.Get(id) as string;
            //return "value";
        }
```

My jquery, and have error when console.log(data) it return null.  :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var refreshId = setInterval(function () {
                var key = ['key1', 'key2'];
                $.each(key, function (indext, itemData) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "api/Quote/" + itemData + "",
                        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                        success: function (data) {
                            console.log(data);
                            var x = JSON.parse(data);
                            //var items = [];
                            //items.push({ key: itemData, value: data });
                            //console.log(items);
                        }
                    });
                })
            }, 5000);
        });
```

I want to get keys (key1, key2) from cache and return data is a json object.
Help me, please! Thank you very much!

Comment: Which language/framework is that? It looks like the error might be rather in your backend code, than in the javascript. Your question should be tagged accoridingly.

Comment: Adjust `contentType` to `application/json` ?

Comment: I fixed in QuoteControllers: changed string Post(string id) = object Post(string id) and delete as string in funtion. But I don't know to get key from Cache. Help me, pleaze